# For which $p\in\mathbb{R}$ does $f_n(x)=\frac{nx^p}{1+n^2x^2}dx$, where $n\geq 1$, become integrable on $(0,\infty)$ with respect to Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question**: For which $p\in\mathbb{R}$ does the family of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{nx^p}{1+n^2x^2}$ $(n\geq1)$ have an integrable upper bound on $(0,\infty)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

**My Attempt**:  First, note that $\frac{nx^p}{1+n^2x^2}=\frac{x^p}{\frac{1}{n}+nx^2}$.  Now, $\frac{d}{dn}(1+nx^2)\approx-\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2=0$ (to minimize).  Therefore, $x^2=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and so $n=\frac{1}{x}$ whenever $x\leq1$ since $n\geq1$ by assumption.  Thus, $\min_n(\frac{1}{1/x}+\frac{1}{x}x^2)=2x$, and so $\sup_n(\frac{nx^p}{1+n^2x^2})\approx\frac{x^p}{2x}$.  Now, we have that $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{p-1}dx<\infty$ whenever $p>0$.  Now, as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac{nx^p}{1+n^2x^2}\rightarrow\frac{nx^p}{n^2x^2}=\frac{x^{p-2}}{n}\leq x^{p-2}$, since $n\geq1$.  So, $\int_0^1 x^{p-2}dx<\infty$ if $p<1$.  Hence we have an integrable upper bound whenever $p\in(0,1)$.

Comment: The change of variables $u=nx$  gives $\frac{1}{n^p}\int^\infty_0\frac{u^p}{1+u^2}\,du$

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  but I'm not sure if that would help, or if my original attempt is then off...

Comment: Let $I_p=\int^\infty_0\frac{u^p}{1+u^2}\,du$.

1. If $p<-1$, then $I_p\geq\frac12\int^1_0u^p\,du=\infty$

2. If $-1<p<0$, the $I_p<\infty$ and so $\frac{1}
{n^p}I_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$

3. If $0<p<1$, $I_p<\infty$ and so $\frac{1}{n^p}I_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$

4. If $1\leq p$, then $I_p=\infty$

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.  So my original attempt is correct, but that is another way to do it, right?

Comment: There is also convergence for $p=0$. Other than that, the conclusions are the same. Changing variables here had the fortunate consequence that $n$ is decoupled from the integral.

Comment: @User7238 why you differentiate with respect to n?

Comment: @rose The goal is to minimize the denominator so I can find the supremum of $f_n(x)$ in hopes to find an integrable upper bound.  So I wanted to get the denominator in terms of just one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variables $u=nx$ gives
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{nx^p}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{n^p}\int^\infty_0\frac{u^p}{1+u^2}\,du=\frac{1}{n^p}I_p$$

1. If $p<-1$, then $I_p\geq\frac12\int^1_0u^p\,du=\infty$
2. If $-1<p<0$, the $I_p<\infty$ and so $\frac{1}
   {n^p}I_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$
3. If $0<p<1$, $I_p<\infty$ and so $\frac{1}{n^p}I_p\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$
4. If $1\leq p$, then $I_p=\infty$
5. When $p=0$, you get $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: So, just out of curiosity, for more of these types of problems, would a change of variables be a better way to start them (in general) than the way I did it?  Are there any other ways of going about these problems that you can see?

Comment: It is not a general method, it was a fortunate event that things for decoupled. Dominated convergence would be a general strategy, but then we may have to split the integrals or find good dominating functions. When that seems to not be obvious, then a change of variables may help.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a simple way to know that $I_p$ is convergent or not rather than the direct computations?